# Uiatomator package smack does not exist error

Tags: android, testing, junit, asmack, android-uiautomator

Is it possible to use asmack, login to jabber account andsending messages with uiautomator ?? I tried to do it but when compilig my testProject to jar file there is exception:

"Compiling 1 source file to (...) error: package org.jivesoftware.smack does not exist"

Any idea why?
I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, should use Robotium framework instead of uiautomator.